# How to delete the nth row of a table, and then update the rowid/auto-increment column of the other rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm doing a Todo-List GUI Project with SQLite for storing the list of tasks.

I can apparently get the nth-row of a table using: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE LIMIT n-1,1`. But apparently there's no option to delete the nth row? Is this something that doesn't exist? Am I missing something here?

I tried to do `DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE rowID = n` since SQLite auto-generates an rowID for the rows in a table. But the problem is after I delete the n-th row, the rowID of the subsequent rows doesn't update. Same case with an auto-increment column

Eg; I've table similar to this

```
| TaskName    | Notes     | Date    |
|-------------|-----------|---------|
| Get milk    | urgent    | ...     |
| Exercise    | leg day   | ..      |
| Meeting     | afternoon | ...     |
```

So ideally what I want is some command that when I tell it to delete the 2nd row should give the output -->

```
| TaskName    | Notes     | Date    |
|-------------|-----------|---------|
| Get milk    | urgent    | ...     |
| Meeting     | afternoon | ...     |
```

And when I do the same command for the 2nd row again should give me -->

```
| TaskName    | Notes     | Date    |
|-------------|-----------|---------|
| Get milk    | urgent    | ...     |
```

What should I be doing/implementing-instead for achieving this basic functionality?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: @forpas I use sqlite, added it

Comment: There is no such thing as the 1st or 2nd or 100th row of a table. Use an ORDER BY clause to order the rows and then set the OFFSET/LIMIT values that you want.

Comment: @forpas Can you elaborate more on how I can use OFFSET/LIMIT to delete the n-th row, I couldn't find a way to do that

Comment: I already mentioned that there is no n-th row without an ORDER BY clause. Read this: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#the_order_by_clause. The important part of the documentation is: *"If a SELECT statement that returns more than one row does not have an ORDER BY clause, the order in which the rows are returned is undefined"*

Comment: first you need a table which defines the order of Notes, then you can use a winfow functio to sort them or at a row_number

Comment: @forpas okay but how can I use that to get what the post is asking? I'm very lost here

Comment: Edit your question and explain what you mean by 2nd row. How is the order of the rows defined.

Comment: On a side note: SQLite doesn't guarantee that rowids start with 1 and get incremented by 1. They only guarantee that the generated rowid is unique. (And with `AUTOINCREMENT`, which is rarely used, it would be guaranteed, that a newer rowid is greater than an old one, but there is no guarantee that there won't be gaps.)

Comment: Consider adding a primary key `id` to this table, so that rows are uniquely identifiable.

Answer (score 1):

Rows in a database table represent an unordered dataset. This table:

| TaskName | Notes | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Get milk | urgent | ... |
| Exercise | leg day | .. |
| Meeting | afternoon | ... |

is the same table as this one:

| TaskName | Notes | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Get milk | urgent | ... |
| Meeting | afternoon | ... |
| Exercise | leg day | .. |

and this:

| TaskName | Notes | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Exercise | leg day | .. |
| Get milk | urgent | ... |
| Meeting | afternoon | ... |

So, if you want to delete the second row, which row do you call "second" here?

Let's assume the dates are unique and you are talking about the rows ordered by the dates. Then:

```
delete from mytable where rowid =
  (select rowid from mytable order by date limit 1,1);
```